# How to display the date in circle having event using FSCalendar?

Tags: swift, fscalendar

I have programatically added FSCalendar using swift and getting the list of events from the api call. A s default the events is displaying like dot below the event date. But I need to display the event in the circle instead of the dot below the date.I tried many ways but it did not work.Is there any way to do it?

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
   return Events[date.GetFormatedDateAsString(format: "dd.MM.YYYY")] ?? 0
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define the DataSource and Delegate for FSCalendar.

For example, i have a Date array for my calendar:

```
var eventsDateArray: [Date] = [SomeDatesExample]
```

So, I use FSCalendarDelegateAppearance to change the appearance of the cell, when my date is rendered, using the methods **titleDefaultColorFor** and **fillDefaultColorFor**:

```
 extension CalendarViewController: FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {

 // Return UIColor for numbers;

 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, 
               appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, 
               titleDefaultColorFor date: Date
 ) -> UIColor? {

      if self.eventsDateArray.contains(date) {
           return Colors.white 
           // Return UIColor for eventsDateArray 
      }

    return Colors.brownDark // Return Default Title Color
}

 // Return UIColor for Background;

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, 
            appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, 
            fillDefaultColorFor date: Date
) -> UIColor? {

    if self.eventsDateArray.contains(date) {
        return Colors.blue // Return UIColor for eventsDateArray
    }

    return Colors.white // Return Default UIColor 
}
}
```

Basically you have to check if your date is being displayed and then return a color to it.

If it doesn't work or you have questions, just call.